# How to update Python application in production

Tags: python, continuous-integration

I wrote a Python application that runs on a Linux server as a daemon. What it does is it listens to a Rabbitmq topic. Whenever there is a new message, the app processes the message doing the following 5 steps.

1. Query database and grab audio data in String format.
2. Convert the audio data to WAV.
3. Calls deep learning model to make prediction to the audio
4. Upload WAV to S3 bucket
5. Send result back to a web API.

The main program runs with multithread:

```
for i in range(2):
    t = threading.Thread(target=process_msg, name='worker-%s' % i)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
while True:
    time.sleep(5)
```

Callback function `process_msg` is the method that does the 5 steps.

Currently this is how I deploy changes to the dev server.

1. Kill active process of the app
2. Do `git pull` to get updates
3. Start the app again.

This manual process is ok for dev, but it is no good for production. Because if I stop the application while it is in the middle of processing a message, it would exit without completing the job. What is the best way to CICD this app without interrupting the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. 
Here is the simplest way i can think of for you.

**CI/CD**

1. don't use git as code delivery infrastructure.
   run a private pip repository and create versioned pip packages every time
   you want to release new code - will have you also to get controll of what features are being released..
2. Use Jenkins to automate the process
3. When you what to deploy new code all you do is pip install -U my_app=1.2.3
   on the server, and then just restarting the app.

**To not interrupt a process, also few options**..

here is one:

run your code as a service (systemd, systemv, upstart).
 after you install your code (with pip hopefully), you can use the following  command`service my_app restart`

in your app add some code to listen to SIGTERM
eg:

```
import signal

def handler_stop_signals(*args, **kwargs):
    """ Handle system signals
    only SIGTERM expected to trigger this"""

    logger.info('Shutting down gracefully ')
    # wait for all tasks to finish before exiting 


signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handler_stop_signals)
```

Every time you restart your app, this handler will be calledback and execute the logic you will write to gracefully shut down.

**tldr**:

Use Jenkins to release pip packages of your code.
Use Jenkins to deploy your pip packages to the target server.
Adjust your code to listen to system signals and act accordingly

ps:
 more advanced solution could be (linux only solution) is to package your code into debian packages and ship them.
you can use tools like [debpackager](https://github.com/urban48/debpackager) to achieve that

Comment: This is helpful. Two questions: does `SIGTERM` come from command like `service my-app stop`? I am using multithread in the main process to deal with rabbitmq messages (code added to main post). How exactly should I do to wait till all threads finish upon the terminate signal inside `hanldler_stop_signals`?

Comment: 1. yes, by default(with systemD), a SIGTERM is sent, followed by 90 seconds of waiting followed by a SIGKILL.  
2. hanldler_stop_signals should be in your main thread and it will listen to signals from the system. once signal is received it will be triggered. You need to write thre logic to properly stop your tasks, how you wait? it's something you need to figure out, since it depends on your implementation. just an idea: is to stop consuming from rabbitMq, use internal queue to store tasks from rabbit before processing, and just wait till its empty..

Comment: @ddd If you found my answer helpful please consider accepting it